# Concatenate arrays using iteration in name with bash

Tags: arrays, bash, iteration, concatenation

I would like to concatenate unlimited numbers of arrays using shortest lines possible, so for this I did the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a list1=("element1")
declare -a list2=("element2")
declare -a list3=("element3")
declare -a list4=("element4")
declare -a list
for i in {1..4}
do
   list=( ${list[@]} ${list$i[@]} )
done
echo ${list[*]}
```

But the code above is not working because $i is not seen as variable and the error is: ${list$i[@]} bad substitution

Comment: `using shortest lines ` then why do you use so many spaces? `to concatenate unlimited numbers` you want to _output_ them or store them in an array? Please be specific.

Comment: Unlimited? Do you really want to create an unlimited number of variables?

Comment: do not care of spaces, I used for better view. I want to have all elements in one array first, surely I will use elements later but how could I use a variable as number in array name for this concatenation?

Comment: just saying unlimited number of arrays, this is limited to 10 at first but later I want to add mores so they could be 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code outputs all 4 lists concatenated together.

```
eval echo \${list{1..4}[*]}
```

This code runs filename expansion over the result of list elements (`*` is replaced by filenames). Consider sacrificing 4 characters and doing `\"\${list{1..4}[*]}\"`.

Note that eval is evil https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048 and such code is confusing. I wouldn't write such code in a real script - I would definitely use a loop. Use shellcheck to check your scripts.

Comment: I'm sorry but something is not good, finally I get all elements in one array but they don't have double quotas anymore and when I try to use the final array with a for loop to get elements one by one it is seen all elements as one. This is not good.

Comment: The code I presented does not put elements in an array. It outputs them. As I understood, the goal was to _output_ them in _shortest_ lines possible. `finally I get all elements in one array` then you are not using the code I presented in this answer (?). Do you actually need for it be _shortest_ as possible? See the other answer - it properly handles quoting. Check your scripts with shellcheck

Answer (score 1):

You can use variable indirection:

```
for i in {1..4} ; do
    ref="list$i[@]"
    list+=("${!ref}")
done
echo "${list[@]}"
```

Comment: You need double-quotes around `${!ref}` -- without them, it'll be subject to the usual word-splitting and wildcard-expansion messiness.

Comment: not working, I have no error but when printing using echo I have just first element1

Comment: @antonio1: Weird, it works for me with your example.